# Nested For Loop for music visualiser not iterating (p5.js)

Tags: javascript, for-loop, fft, nested-loops, p5.js

I am trying to create some scales measuring sound frequency for a music visualiser project. They are meant to display 4 different frequencies ( bass, lowMid, highMid and treble in a 2x2 grid pattern.  I'm nearly there I have my rectangles but the needle which measures and shows the frequency itself is only iterating for the top row x and not the bottom row. I'm pretty new to JavaScript so I'm sure it could be something very simple that I'm missing.

```
    // draw the plots to the screen
    this.draw = function() {
        //create an array amplitude values from the fft.
        var spectrum = fourier.analyze();
        //iterator for selecting frequency bin.
        var currentBin = 0;
        push();
        fill('#f0f2d2');
        //nested for loop to place plots in 2*2 grid.
        for(var i = 0; i < this.plotsDown; i++) {
            for(var j = 0; j < this.plotsAcross; j++) {

                //calculate the size of the plots
                var x = this.pad * j * 10;
                var y = height/20 * i * 10;
                var w = (width - this.pad) / this.plotsAcross;
                var h = (height - this.pad) / this.plotsDown;

                //draw a rectangle at that location and size
                rect(x, y, w, h);

                //add on the ticks
                this.ticks((x + w/2), h, this.frequencyBins[i])

                var energy = fourier.getEnergy(this.frequencyBins[currentBin]);

                //add the needle
                this.needle(energy, (x + w/2), h)

                currentBin++;
            }
        }

        pop();
    };
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example I think this is in order.. The loops seem to be be alright. It would be helpful to be able to run the code and console.log variables to see what's happening. There are also things like `this.needle` and `this.pad` that people don't know about and how they work.Try adding a link to a editor.p5js.org for example. (sometimes when creating such an simplified example, you can even stumble upon what wrong yourself ;))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try changing

`this.ticks((x + w/2), h, this.frequencyBins[i])`

to

`this.ticks((x + w/2), y + h, this.frequencyBins[i])`,

and changing

`this.needle(energy, (x + w/2), h)`

to

`this.needle(energy, (x + w/2), y + h)`.

This should work.